# What is a required for a creature to be capable of diving into lava lakes?

Tags: volcanoes

So far along the lines of this matter, I've decided that if they were 5'8" and humanoid, composed of something similar to Tungsten, so they don't melt or burn, they would weigh around 3,846lbs/1,744.5kgs, which seems unlikely for a generally humanoid form to support. Assuming they have extremely efficient (for strength and endurance) muscles and are capable of supporting that mass, could they even venture outside a volcano without crushing or sinking into the ground beneath them?

If we say their skin and bodily processes can be sustained by an odd diet between carnivore and ingesting lava rocks, is it possible for them to have a body temp around a "low" 120 degrees Celsius?

Suppose they went into the ocean at some point, is biological insulation capable of supporting cold and hot extremes alike? Been trying to make this character with as little magic as possible, but there's already a psion, so it's not off the board completely.

Creature could also potentially have scales, but would it be even stronger than the metal-like flesh? Or some sort of aid to insulation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94681/discussion-on-question-by-crimson-rain-what-is-a-required-for-a-creature-to-be-c).

Answer (score 2):

### It can't be done with normal Biology.

Lava is molten rock. It has a surface temperature of 700 to 1200 °C. That is hot enough to destroy ANY protein. Lava is also incredibly dense with 3100 km/m³ - which is 3.1 times as dense as water and all living beings we know. To survive and get under the lava surface, you'd have to have beings that are exclusively made from metal with melting points far beyond those temperatures so they sink in lava and do not get soft and molten.

Such a metal being is by FAR out of the scope of biology, and you can pretty much invent everything about it. It won't be scientifically feasable in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that lava is nowhere as swimmable as water.

It is almost as dense as the rock surrounding it, and [you can actually walk on lava](https://youtu.be/begW9JWtSv4).

You can't swim in it, even if you can touch it without getting hurt.